# Lenova PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable and PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM

Tags: windows, boot

My laptop is unable to boot, due to this error:

> Lenova PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable and PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM

Actually, I had deleted a system reserved directory when I was installing a new OS.

How do I recover from this?

My system is a Lenova B50.

Comment: Are you trying to do a PXE boot? If not, then change your boot order from bios to boot from your hard disk or other media.

Comment: Background for OP: "My laptop is unable to boot, due to this error:". No. That is not the error preventing it to boot. That is a message from attempted netboot after the regular/intended boot failed.